# File "<stdin>", line 1 error en visual studio code

Tags: python, vscode

Estaba trabajando con visual estudio code todos mis archivos funcionaban perfectamente pero de repente comenzó a aparecer el siguiente error cada vez que intento correr algo. Funciona en otros editores incluso en el IDLE. NO entiendo que o por que dejo de funcionar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa no es la terminal, es el intérprete interactivo de  python

Answer (score 1):

Estás ejecutando el script desde el propio intérprete de Python, es por ello que da el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo en mi caso tengo PowerShell que es un intérprete de comandos donde si me deja ejecutar el script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes correr los scripts directamente desde el terminal (aunque es preferible que lo configures bien en VSC), pasos:

1. Tecla WINDOWS + R
2. Escribes CMD
3. Enter
4. Escribes: python {dirección completa del fichero}
5. Enter

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Posible solución**

Seguramente has abierto el intérprete sin querar aquí he imitado lo que te ha sucedido, solo hace falta que llames a la función exit() y ya te aparecerá tu intérprete de comandos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo para responder tan detalladamente. En verdad eso fue lo que me sucedió. (Una tonteria) muchas gracias!!!!!!